# Right way to free memory

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I create program with using priority queue and I need to free all memory at the end of program. I use Valgrind to find memory-leaks and I get warning in this code:

```
int len;

//vlozeni prvniho prvku
len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d,%d", startX, startY);
char *link = malloc(len + 1);
sprintf(link,"%d,%d", startX, startY);
priq_push(queue, link, 0);

while(1)
{
    for(some_condition)
    {
        if(another_condition)
        {
            len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d,%d", neighbourX, neighbourY);
            link = realloc(NULL, len + 1);
            sprintf(link,"%d,%d", neighbourX, neighbourY);
            priq_push(queue, link, elementHeight + heights[neighbourX][neighbourY]);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(f == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
}

free(link);
```

With this code I get from Valgrind this warning:

```
4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==9069==    at 0x4C2C857: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==9069==    by 0x401233: main (main.c:229)
==9069== 
==9069== 7,628,843 bytes in 932,764 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==9069==    at 0x4C2C857: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==9069==    by 0x4C2C9CB: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:687)
==9069==    by 0x401554: main (main.c:305)
```

Line 291 is first malloc: `char *link = malloc(len + 1);`

What I'm doing wrong?

edit.

```
void priq_push(priority_queue q, void *data, int height)
{
    q_elem_t *b;
    int n, m;

    if (q->position >= q->alloc) 
    {
        q->alloc *= 2;
        b = q->buffer = realloc(q->buffer, sizeof(q_elem_t) * q->alloc);
    } 
    else
    {
        b = q->buffer;
    }

    n = q->position++;
    /* append at end, then up heap */
    while ((m = n / 2) && height < b[m].height)
    {
        b[n] = b[m];
        n = m;
    }
    b[n].data = data;
    b[n].height = height;
}

/* remove top item. returns 0 if empty. *priority can be null. */
void * priq_pop(priority_queue q, int *height)
{
    void *out;
    if (q->position == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    q_elem_t *b = q->buffer;

    out = b[1].data;
    if (height)
    {
        *height = b[1].height;
    }

    /* pull last item to top, then down heap. */
    --q->position;

    int n = 1, m;
    while ((m = n * 2) < q->position) 
    {
        if (m + 1 < q->position && b[m].height > b[m + 1].height)
        {
            m++;
        }

        if (b[q->position].height <= b[m].height)
        {
            break;
        }
        b[n] = b[m];
        n = m;
    }

    b[n] = b[q->position];
    if (q->position < q->alloc / 2 && q->position >= 16)
    q->buffer = realloc(q->buffer, (q->alloc /= 2) * sizeof(b[0]));

    return out;
}
```

and I write by myself function, which will free queue at the end

```
void free_queue(priority_queue queue)
{
    free(queue->buffer);
    free(queue);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priority queue holds on to the pointers that you pass it. Which means that the queue must assume ownership of the memory. You need the code that pulls items off the queue to call `free` when it is dealt with each item.

We cannot see that code, it's the code that actually calls `priq_pop`. But the leak reporting seems to indicate that the code that calls `priq_pop` is not freeing the returned items.

Your steps to resolve this are:

1. Replace the `realloc` with `malloc` which is equivalent but reads better.
2. Remove the `free(link)` at the end of the push loop. That is incorrect since the queue owns the memory.
3. Add calls to `free()` whenever you call `priq_pop` and have finished dealing with the returned item.

Comment: As PriorityQueue I used existing implementation, so I'm not sure, if priority queue is holder of memory.  I'll add push and pop function to my question.

Comment: And when I replace `realloc` with `free` and `malloc`, then my program stop working.

Comment: @Sk1X1 Why did you replace `realloc` with `free` and `malloc`? That would only be appropriate if the queue did not own the memory. And it is very clear from your code that the queue does not take a copy of the memory and therefore owns it.

Answer (score 0):

You should eventually deallocate all links pushed in the queue.